# How to cache deployment image in gitlab-ci?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm creating a `gitlab-ci` deployment stage that requires some more libraries than existing in my image. In this example, I'm adding `ssh` (in real world, I want to add many more libs):

```
image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11
...

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - which ssh || (apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y ssh)
    - chmod 600 ${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}
    ...
```

Question: how can I tell gitlab runner to cache the image that I'm building in the deploy stage, and reuse it for all deployment runs in future? Because as written, the library installation takes place for each and every deployment, even if nothing changed between runs.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab can only cache files/directories, but because of the way apt works, there is no easy way to tell it to cache installs you've done this way. You also cannot "cache" the image.

There are two options I see:

1. Create or use a docker image that already includes your dependencies.

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11
RUN apt update && apt install -y foo bar baz
```

Then build/push the image the image to dockerhub, then change the `image:` in the yaml:

```yaml
image: membersound/maven-openjdk11-with-deps:latest
```

OR simply choose an image that already has all the dependencies you want! There are many useful docker images out there with useful tools installed. For example [`octopusdeploy/worker-tools`](https://hub.docker.com/r/octopusdeploy/worker-tools) comes with many runtimes and tools installed (java, python, AWS CLI, kubectl, and much more).

2. attempt to cache the deb packages and install from the deb packages. (beware this is ugly)

Commit a bash script as so to a file like `install-deps.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PACKAGES="wget jq foo bar baz"

if [ ! -d "./.deb_packages" ]; then
  apt update && apt --download-only install -y ${PACKAGES}
  cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb ./.deb_packages
fi

apt install -y ./.deb_packages/*.deb
```

This should cause the debian files to be cached in the directory `./.deb_packages`. You can then configure gitlab to cache them so you can use them later.

```yaml
my_job:
  before_script:
    - install-deps.sh
  script:
    -  ...
  cache:
    paths:
      - ./.deb_packages
```